# NodeJS kafka producer using kafkaJS library not working

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm writting a kafka producer in NodeJS using kafkaJS library.

Below is my sample code. 
It makes connection with the kafka broker and sends message to a kafka topic "topic-name".

**KafkaJS-Producer.js**

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['localhost:9092']
})

const producer = kafka.producer() 

async () => {
  await producer.connect()
  await producer.send({
    topic: 'topic-name',
    messages: [
      { key: 'key1', value: 'hello world' },
      { key: 'key2', value: 'hey hey!' }
    ],
  })
  await producer.disconnect()
}
```

I ran the code with no error.

```
node SampleProducer.js
```

Consuming messages from topic as below:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic-name --from-beginning
```

But, I could not see any message being delivered to Kafka Topic.

What can be the reason for this?

**Note:**

Kafka is running on localhost.
Topic is also created.

**Resources:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafkajs
https://kafka.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Resolved:**

Actually, the issue was that the arrow function which was producing messages was not invoked. I made some changes to the code and it is working fine now:

```
var sendMessage = async () => {
  await producer.connect()
  await producer.send({
    topic: 'topic-name',
    messages: [
      { key: 'key1', value: 'hello world' },
      { key: 'key2', value: 'hey hey!' }
    ],
  })
  await producer.disconnect()
}

sendMessage();
```